# Странная работа цикла и Multimap

Tags: java

```
private Multimap<String, Socket> onlineUsers = ArrayListMultimap.create();
UsersMessage = onlineUsers.get(username);
SocketThread.sendLogOff(ListSocket.UsersMessage, username, computername);
for (Socket m : UsersMessage) {
      kss++;
      onlineUsers.remove(username, m);
}
```

Если есть onlineUsers.remove(username, m), то почему-то цикл выполняется один раз, а если нету, то то количество раз, сколько находится в UsersMessage
Что такое?

Answer (score 1):

Вы удаляете из коллекции по которой итерируете. Для этого надо Iterator использовать.

```
Iterator<String> iterator = UsersMessage.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: Так же не удаляет